# Ensuring compatibility between packages without adding one of them to the dependencies

Tags: python, pip, continuous-integration, dependencies, dependency-management

I am writing a custom library that needs to be compatible with `apache-airflow=2.2.5'.

The library itself does not need Airflow, and adding it to the dependencies massively increases the install time and makes it incompatible with other packages (notably, Jupyter).

What would be the standard way of ensuring compatibility between this package and Airflow (or any other package for that matter), without explicitly adding it to the dependencies? I thought that adding another step to the CI pipeline that would verify that could solve it (which library would I use though?)

Comment: If you need this compatibility then yes, adding airflow as a test dependency and writing some regular integration tests that ensure these two properly work together is the right way to go imho.

Comment: Thanks, didn't think of writing integration tests to make sure that it can work together. But if I didn't want to add Airflow explicitly, would adding a step in the pipeline that would fail if package was not compatible with Airflow a bad practice?

Comment: That is exactly part of the integration test: add airflow to the testing dependencies and see if it works during the test runs. That is basically ***exactly*** what an integration test is supposed to be used for.

Comment: thanks, it's clarifying. Will add an integration test then.